# Copying files between Windows servers that are 60 minutes old or newer

Tags: powershell, robocopy, xcopy, sql-agent

Quick need: Within a SQL Agent job step, I am looking for a way to copy files newer than 60 minutes "ago" to another server. I don't want to re-copy any files older than that. So, copy, xcopy, robocopy are all possibilities as this is a Windows 2008 or higher server.

Background: I'm wiring up a process where serverA has a folder where an ERP application is dumping flat text files to that folder. I need to copy the "newest files" once per hour to serverB so that another application (an SSIS package that kicks off every 60 minutes) can process the file and save the data into SQL Server. In order to only copy "new files" that appear and not copy anything I've already copied over (if exists won't work because I will remove the copied file after SSIS processes it) I need to basically copy files that are only 60 minutes old, or newer and exclude all other files.

For what its worth, the method used will be a SQL Agent Job step so CmdExec and Powershell are both allowed (I am new to PowerShell so I am leaning toward Robocopy).

Answer (score 0):

My solution (and my first PowerShell script) was to use PowerShell's 'Where-Object'  cmdlet to pipe only the files that were 60 minutes old or newer to 'Get-ChildItem'  and then use 'Copy-Item' within foreach as below:

```
$srcPath = '\\serverA\ERP\Outbox\'
$destPath = 'C:\ERP\FromERP\Inbox\'
# target files where LastWriteTime >= 60 minutes "ago"
$age = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60)
#Write-Output "$age"
$newFiles = Get-ChildItem $srcPath | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $age }
#Write-Output "$newFiles"
foreach ($newFile in $newFiles) {
    #Write-Output "Copying $newFile to $destPath"
    Copy-Item $newFile.FullName -Destination "$($destPath)$($newFile)"
}
```

Some of the lines that are commented were simply for debugging purposes but I left them in to help in understanding what is going on.

Note: I experimented with copy, xcopy and robocopy and I think that with some crafty batch language syntax I saw elsewhere on SO I could have gotten them to work (robocopy has a MAXAGE argument but the lowest value is 1 day, which is not granular enough for minutes) but PowerShell really felt simpler and more elegant.

Hopefully someone else can make use of the technique.

Comment: Update: to prevent syntax errors when running this code within a SQL Agent step, change the above:

`Copy-Item $newFile.FullName -Destination "$($destPath)$($newFile)"`

to:

`Copy-Item $newFile.FullName -Destination "$destPath$newFile"`